# Need kql query to find status of the agent

Tags: azure, kql, agent

need to find out servers where both AMA and MMA is installed.

Heartbeat
| summarize lastHeartbeat = max(TimeGenerated) by Computer
| project Computer, lastHeartbeat, AgentType = lastHeartbeat.Properties["agentType"]
| where tostring(AgentType) in ("AMA", "MMA")
| summarize AgentTypes = make_set(AgentType) by Computer
| where array_length(AgentTypes) == 2

Path expression Properties_agentType source must be scalar of type 'dynamic'. Received a source of type datetime instead

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the above error is you are trying to get the `Properties["agentType"]` from a `datetime` type column and not from a **dynamic type** column.

[image]

The `Timegenerated` column from the [Heartbeat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/heartbeat#columns) table is of datetime type and so the type of `lastHeartbeat` also the same as below sample.

[image]

So, to avoid the error, ensure that you are only accessing the properties from an array type.